# find a string if match then copy line string onwards

Tags: bash

I want to let a variable contain below string
v1="select * from tablename where id > 1000 "

now I want convert this select to delete but through bash/ksh script.

like when string "from" matched rest part of line copied to a variable and it is easily convert  to delete statements , like below line
 delete from tablename where id > 1000 ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this:

```
v1="select c1,c2 from tablename where id > 1000"
sed '/select .* from /s/select .* from/delete from/' <<< "$v1"
delete from tablename where id > 1000
```

Comment: actually that select is going to pass as a parameter to bash script,so sometime select few column names also passed that time it looks like  v1="select c1,c2 from tablename where id > 1000 " so after sed it should be delete from tablename where id > 1000

Comment: So you to replace `select a, b, c, from ` by `delete from `?

Comment: how we replace , it comes dynamically ,some time may be single column name comes some times multiple .like select c1 from tablename where id > 1000 sometime select c1,c2 from tablename where id > 1000 and sometime select * from tablename where id > 1000

Comment: You need to provide details, what's not working. You can see output of sed from answer above, is that not what you expect?

Comment: yes ,see some time v1 values select c1 from tablename where id > 1000 sometime select c1,c2 from tablename where id > 1000 and sometime select * from tablename where id > 1000  , i have to consider all cases ?

Comment: Yes but output will always be `delete from tablename where id > 1000` in all these cases. Above sed will work for all of these inputs you wrote.

Comment: yes output will be always delete from tablename where id > 1000 .which commands i have to use

Comment: ok then what's the problem? Above sed will work for all of these inputs you wrote.

Comment: You just sed command from above answer and run against your input file as: `sed '/select .* from /s/select .* from/delete from/' file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed 's/select .* \(from .*\)/delete \1/' sqlfile.txt
```